# file Path not picking in vb.net

Tags: .net, vb.net

I have an existing file and included in project under Templates folder, I am trying to open it using below code but its giving me an error "File not found"

```
oDoc = oWord.Documents.Open("\Templates\TestTemplate.docx")
```

please advise how to pass the file available under project

Comment: Open it with the full file path, including network share or drive letter.

Comment: yes that is working, but it will not work if I send an exe at outside my network, hence I want go give path of my file available under project root folder..

Comment: you can use System.Environment.CurrentDirectory() &  "\Templates\TestTemplate.docx"

Answer (score 0):

Use Code:

```
oDoc = oWord.Documents.Open("..\Templates\TestTemplate.docx")
```

Explanation:

Your exe will be under bin->debug/release folder. This '..\' is used to point one step backward in the path.

Say for example, if your 'Templates' folder is found in the folder where your 'bin' folder is placed.Then you can get the path by giving the above piece of code.

Hope this helps.